# bitcoind with jsonRPCClient.php not working

Tags: php, bitcoin, json-rpc, bitcoind

i have a problem when use jsonRPCClient to get info bitcoin on my vps ubuntu, and i dont'n know how can fix it.

```
<?php
require_once 'jsonRPCClient.php';
$bitcoin = new jsonRPCClient('http://user:password@127.0.0.1:8332/');
echo "<pre>\n";
print_r($bitcoin->getinfo());
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

my config:

```
server=1
rpcuser=username
rpcpassword=pass123
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
daemon=1
```

it has error:

```
    Warning:  fopen(http://...@127.0.0.1:8332/): failed to open stream: Connection refused in /var/www/.../jsonRPCClient.php on line 133

    Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to connect to http://user:password@127.0.0.1:8332/' in /var/www/.../jsonRPCClient.php:141
    Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/.../common.php(15): jsonRPCClient->__call('getinfo', Array)
    #1 /var/www/.../common.php(15): jsonRPCClient->getinfo()
    #2 /var/www/.../index.php(3): include('/var/www/coinba...')
    #3 {main}

  thrown in /var/www/.../jsonRPCClient.php on line 141
```

how to fix it, help me, please!!!

Comment: The error you're getting seems to indicate bitcoin isn't listening on port 8332, or something is blocking the connection to it.  Can you run `sudo netstat -anop | grep LISTEN` and confirm you see bitcoind listening on 8332?

Comment: I found out that it is impossible to use the config repeatedly duplicative information, i removed and installed bitcoind, it's done, thank you.

Answer (score -3):

It would appear your `username` and `password` do not match you `bitcoin.conf` file.

```
rpcuser=username
rpcpassword=pass123

('http://user:password@127.0.0.1:8332/');
```

It can be difficult to debug with jsonRPCclient for this exact reason.  The jsonRPCClient library uses `fopen()` and will throw an exception saying "Unable to connect" if it receives a 404 or 500 error from bitcoind. This prevents you from being able to see error messages generated by bitcoind.

Also it is recommended to use `easybitcoin` library instead of jsonRPCClient.

[Source](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)#PHP)

Instead, follow the above link, use the easybitcoin.php library, and give this a try.

```
require("easybitcoin.php");
$bitcoin = new Bitcoin("username", "pass123");

$info = $bitcoin->getinfo();
print_r($info);
```